# "Below certain years" or "Under certain years"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is appropriate for the following case, "**below** certain years" or "**under** certain years"?

> This person has 2 children **below** / **under** 2 years.

I saw both in use and I'm sure if they are both correct. (Does it have something to do with British or American English?)

Comment: English is English in most cases. This is not on the road, in the road.

Comment: There's no reason to suppose either preposition usage is more common on one side of the Atlantic than the other, but I'd be pretty sure that ***years*** would usually *not* be explicitly specified (and when it *is* present, it's often expanded to *below/under 2 **years of age*** anyway).

Comment: So I understand that both are correct and not strange to the native English speaker ears. Right?

Comment: below 2 years old OR under 2 years old. except in speech, where the old is not necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't say either, I'd be more likely to say "less than 2 years old".  That doesn't only apply to age comparisons, but also other time comparisons.  Example: "You have been here for less than two years".  Not saying under/below is wrong, but I wouldn't naturally choose those terms in these cases.

Comment: On the British Airways site, I found they say 'under 2 years'. (see here: https://www.britishairways.com/cms/global/pdfs/ba_travel_trade/bmi_policies/children/bmi_children_infants.pdf. and also here (under 2 or under 12): https://www.britishairways.com/en-it/information/family-travel/seating